# Is this deleting pointer behavior normal?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class binary_node {
public:
    T data;
    binary_node<T> *left;
    binary_node<T> *right;

    binary_node(const T& data)
        :data(data), left(NULL), right(NULL) {
    }
};

int main() {
    binary_node<int>* node = new binary_node<int>(10);
    node->left = new binary_node<int>(1);
    node->right = new binary_node<int>(50);

    binary_node<int>* ptr = node->left;

    delete ptr;
    ptr = NULL;

    if (node->left == NULL) {
        cout << "????";
    }
    else {
        cout << node->left->data << endl;
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect `node->left == NULL`, but the result is totally unexpected even though the data of `node->left` is garbage. I'm using Visual C++ 2010, could anyone help me explain this behavior?

**EDIT**
On the other hand, it works just fine when traversing and delete node by node like this:

```
    ~linkedlist() {
#if DEBUG
        cout << "~linkedlist() called.\n";
#endif
        while (head != NULL) {
#if DEBUG
            cout << "delete node: " << head->data << '\n';
#endif
            node<T>* temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = NULL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: My guess, after your have called delete your `ptr` doesn't really point to any thing so setting it to `NULL` will not affect `node->left`.

Comment: Your `ptr` is just a copy of the pointer stored in `node->left`, writing to it doesn't change `node->left`. `binary_node<int>* &ptr = node->left;` would work the way you expect.

Comment: Your list traversal is different. You set `head` to another value, and presumably the last element's `next` node is set to NULL elsewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are deleting the the data allocated to `node->left` object ie. the `new binary_node<int>(50)` object.

However you are deleting via another pointer. You then NULL that other pointer

node->left  is never set to null. As such the contents of whatever it points (deallocated memory) is is what it points to.

try this:

```
binary_node<int>** ptr = &(node->left); 

delete *ptr; 
*ptr = NULL;
```

Or this

```
delete node->left; 
node->left = NULL;
```

Here is an improved depiction I made to show what I'm saying:
[image]

Comment: I still don't get it. When I delete my linkedlist nodes, I traverse the whole list and use a temporary pointer to hold the current node then delete it without using `pointer to pointer` or `reference to pointer` and it works just fine. How are these two different? See my edit.

Comment: @Chan: The underlying object is deleted alright in both cases. However, in the linked list case, the pointer to `head` is overwritten so you won't have a dangling pointer. In the binary tree case, `node->left` pointer **value** is never modified, so it will keep pointing to the memory location of the node even after the memory is deallocated.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Thanks. I see your point but I still think that behavior is strange! Many data structure books that I read use that temporary technique to delete pointer and I've been using for years.

Comment: @Chan: They use temporary pointer in the case of linked list, since they want to 1) delete underlying object pointed to by `head` pointer and 2) make `head` pointer point to the next object in the list. If you do 2 first, then you lose reference to the undeleted first object (memory leak). If you do 1 first, then you lose reference to the next object (also memory leak, and data loss). So the temporary pointer is used make that 2 operations possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `node->left` to `NULL` instead of `ptr` to `NULL`.

`delete` will **not** set the pointer passed in to `NULL`. Even **if** it does, it will not be able to modify `node->left`

Comment: Delete does not set the pointer to `NULL`, which is why it has to be done manually.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer is actually just a number. Number which determines a place in a memory. You have two pointers pointing to the same place in a memory: `ptr` and `node->left`. Then you delete the memory and reset one of the pointers to `NULL`, but of course that does **not** make the other pointer to be reset too.